# Import 2D GML file via OGR2OGR fails with "Did not get at least 3 values or invalid number of set of coordinates"

Tags: ogr2ogr, gml, dimensions

I have a GML file that seems to mix

```
<gml:posList srsDimension="2">
```

and

```
<gml:posList>
```

records. OGR2OGR (understandably) crashes when reading these files:

```
ERROR 1: Did not get at least 3 values or invalid number of set of coordinates <gml:posList>205962.585 476394.629 205957.111 476398.377 205946.834 476405.243 205947.315 476406.680 205945.326 476407.938 205945.374 476407.563 205945.320 476407.086 205944.605 476405.688 205940.987 476399.969 205938.375 476395.992 205937.806 476395.734</gml:posList>
```

I've seen other questions on this subject ([How to debug ogr2ogr ERROR 1: Did not get at least 2 values or invalid number of set of coordinates?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50237/how-to-debug-ogr2ogr-error-1-did-not-get-at-least-2-values-or-invalid-number-of)), suggesting to add -dim 2 to the OGR2OGR commandline, but this doesn't seem to work. OSGeo4W is up-to-date, and using GDAL 1.10 / 1.11 / 2.00 / 2.01.

```
C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\ogr2ogr -dim 3 -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=dbserver user=test password=test dbname=db" mygml.gml -dim 3 -overwrite -progress
```

It seems the parameter is completely ignored. All objects are 2D, so this line (with -dim 3) should fail on the first object; it doesn't. Setting this to 2 also doesn't change anything. (I added two -dim parameters as a test - also doesn't change anything).

Simply skipping objects (--skipfailures) isn't really an option since I have no idea how many objects are affected.

I have about 50GB worth of GML meaning a simple open & replace job is quite hard.

Does anyone know why OGR2OGR ignores my parameter, or can perhaps offer another solution?

Answer (score 1):

Again I answer my own question.

See the ticket at https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/6597